# Compactness of a set of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

During lunch break, somebody submitted us this problem today:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers and $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function.
>
> Let $K=\{u\in C^1([a,b],\mathbb R), u'=F\circ u\}$
>
> Prove $K$ is compact (with respect to the sup norm)

Nobody in my class has solved it.

I've thought of setting an operator $T$such that $T:u\to u'-F\circ u$ and considering its fixed points, but $T$ is not linear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval sorry for the typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: What is $u'$ here?

Comment: @WilliamStagner it denotes the derivative of $u$.

Comment: It seems that K at least is closed since it is the preimage of {0 = constant function zero} under T. Maybe we can show that it's a closed subset of some ambient compact set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I give you a counterexample:

let $F(x)=x$. Then
$$\{ u \in C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R} ) : u'=u\} \supset \{ \lambda \exp : \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
is not bounded, hence it is not compact.

Comment: I was thinking to this .... Also $F(x)=0$ (constantly) should give a counterexample, as $K=\Bbb R$ in this case.

Comment: What is $\lambda \text{ exp}$?

Comment: @Libertron it's the function $t \mapsto \lambda e^t$.